# Can I get the minimum of 2 columns which is greater than a given value using only one scan of a table

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is my example data (there are no indexes and I do not want to create any):

```
CREATE TABLE tblTest ( a INT , b INT );
INSERT INTO tblTest ( a, b ) VALUES
( 1 , 2 ),
( 5 , 1 ),
( 1 , 4 ),
( 3 , 2 )
```

I want the minimum value in of both column a and column b which is greater then a given value.  E.g. if the given value is 3 then I want 4 to be returned.

This is my current solution:

```
SELECT MIN (subMin) FROM 
(
 SELECT MIN (a) as subMin FROM tblTest
 WHERE a > 3 -- Returns 5
 UNION 
 SELECT MIN (b) as subMin FROM tblTest
 WHERE b > 3 -- Returns 4
)
```

This searches the table twice - once to get `min(a)` once to get `min(b)`.

I believe it should be faster to do this with just one pass.  Is this possible?

Comment: Does sqlite have `LEAST()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use conditional aggregatino for this:

```
select min(case when a > 3 then a end) as minA,
       min(case when b > 3 then b end) as minB
from tblTest;
```

To get the minimum of both values, you can use a SQLite extension, which handles multiple values for `min()`:

```
select min(min(case when a > 3 then a end),
           min(case when b > 3 then b end)
          )
from tblTest
```

The only issue is that the `min` will return `NULL` if either argument is NULL.  You can fix this by doing:

```
select coalesce(min(min(case when a > 3 then a end),
                    min(case when b > 3 then b end)
                   ),
                min(case when a > 3 then a end),
                min(case when b > 3 then b end)
               )
from tblTest
```

This version will return the minimum value, subject to your conditions.  If one of the conditions has no rows, it will still return the minimum of the other value.

Comment: +1 beat me to it, and a more complete answer than I was going to give.

Comment: +1 Great, Thank you - I thought it should be possible,  It is faster this way right?  My only worry is my query plan had `SEARCH TABLE tblTest (~1 rows) ...` whereas your one had `SCAN TABLE tblTest (~4 rows)`.

Comment: @Robert . . . It should only scan the table once to calculate the results.  I do not know why the query plan would be different, but you should try running it on a larger data set to see if there really is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head, you could modify the table and add a min value column to store the minimum value of the two columns. then query that column.

Or you can do this:

```
select min(val)
from
(
    select min(col1, col2) as val
    from table1
)
where 
val > 3
```

The outer SELECT, queries the memory, not the table itself.

Check [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d0661/3)

Comment: Not sure this will work since min( 1 , 4 ) = 1 so it will never find 4.